# I need to compare last 2 line timestamps in a log file to verify if the log is current

Tags: bash, shell

I have a log file which updates the every 60 seconds and each new line

holds the  following format:

```
IP - - [22/Nov/2013:16:51:38 +0000] "GET /some path" 500 305

IP - - [22/Nov/2013:16:52:28 +0000] "GET /some path" 500 305
```

This is so code that I have so far:

```
#! /bin/bash

#This gets the time stamp of the last log

file1=`ssh root@IP  tail -n 1  path/file | cut -d'/' -f3 | awk '{print $1}'` 

sleep 60

#This allows the script to sleep for 60 sec while the logs populate

file2=`ssh root@IP tail -n 1  path/file | cut -d'/' -f3 | awk '{print $1}'`

#This is the 2nd time that the file log is tested


if [ $file1 -eq $file2 ]; then  

#comparing 2 time stamp variables

echo "The Access Logs are NOT current!" 

fi
```

The code doesn't compare the timestamps correctly, it will always echo that

access logs are not current even if they are. I might think there is a conversion

must be done to Unix format but not sure how that be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with this

`[ $file1 -eq $file2 ]`

`file1` and `file2` contain strings such as `2013:16:51:38` and you are running a numeric equality check on this.

Use `[ "$file1" = "$file2" ]` instead. This does a string comparison.

Comment: I've tried double quotes before, and I was getting the same error.

Comment: @user2876750, it's not just about the double-quotes, it's the switch from `eq` to `=`